# How to pass the array inside an array to another array in swift3?

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an array

`[[Optional("Sun"), Optional("Mon"), Optional("Tue"), Optional("Wed"), Optional("Thu"), Optional("Fri"), Optional("Sat")]]`

This is actually an array inside an array at the first index. So i am trying to assign the first index array to another array like this:

```
var daysCombinedFinal = [Any]()

daysCombinedFinal = [daysCombined[0]][0]
```

But i am getting the following error:
[Please see the description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkoLP.png)

Comment: What type has `daysCombined`?

Comment: `[daysCombined[0]][0]` is nonsense.  You are putting the result of `daysCombined[0]` into an array literal and then taking the first value, so it is just `daysCombined[0]` again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
var daysCombinedFinal = [Any?]()
daysCombinedFinal = daysCombined[0]
```

Comment: Array has optional values `Optional("Sun")` so `?` ensures that array values can be optional `nil`